scp, ddns, ssh no connection
ok, here the problem, I found a workaround but I wonder if I can do it otherwise.
This morning I installed and configured DDNS (dynu) and now I can't using scp correctly. Scp from my local pc to OpenWrt router is ok, but scp from my router to pc, or ie; scp root@192.168.1.1:/tmp/backup-*.tar.gz james@pop-os:/media/james/E/openWrt_backup did not work.
kind of error ;
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Connection reset by 169.150.204.5 port 22 or sometimes ; port 22: Connection refused

But, it is working if I comment (#) my ddns domain line in my ubuntu config file ; /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
#search Ninjanoir78.ddnsfree.com

here my openwrt dhcp
root@james:~# cat /etc/config/dhcp

config dnsmasq
        option domainneeded '1'
        option localise_queries '1'
        option rebind_protection '0'
        option local '/lan/'
        option domain 'Ninjanoir78.ddnsfree.com'
        option expandhosts '1'
        option authoritative '1'
        option readethers '1'
        option leasefile '/tmp/dhcp.leases'
        option resolvfile '/tmp/resolv.conf.d/resolv.conf.auto'
        option localservice '1'
        option ednspacket_max '1232'
        option cachesize '1000'
        option port '54'
        list server '192.168.1.1'
        option serversfile '/var/run/adblock-fast/dnsmasq.servers'

config dhcp 'lan'
        option interface 'lan'
        option start '100'
        option limit '150'
        option leasetime '24h'
        option dhcpv4 'server'
        option force '1'
        list dhcp_option '6, 192.168.1.1'
        list dhcp_option '3, 192.168.1.1'

config dhcp 'wan'
        option interface 'wan'
        option ignore '1'

config odhcpd 'odhcpd'
        option maindhcp '0'
        option leasefile '/tmp/hosts/odhcpd'
        option leasetrigger '/usr/sbin/odhcpd-update'
        option loglevel '4'


So if you have a solution to keep it that working without a need to comment the domain line, or do I really need it in my ubuntu resolv.conf ?
thanks

btw, first time I setup ddns, I really need my domain name in my resolf.conf on my pc? It has been automatically add it there

